# Setting up MiKTeX and TeXworks

Tags: miktex, texworks

I'm trying to learn LaTeX, I installed MiKTeX and TeXworks as a editor and gave the path to MiKTeX  in `edit/preference/typesetting`. I'm trying to run some code it gives me an error that the program `pdftext.exe` was not found!

Comment: Did you select `.../MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin` where `.../` means the path to which you installed MiKTex?

Comment: Note also that Miktex 2.9 comes already with Texworks installed. So it should be pre-configured.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your answer was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or edit your answer.

Answer (score 19):

You mentioned that you set the path to MikTeX. It is, however, not enough to set the path to `C:\Program Files\MikTeX 2.9\`. You need to set the path to where the pdflatex.exe is located. This is `.../MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin` as mentioned in the comment above.

The easiest is probably to write this path to the environmental variables in windows. Then `pdflatex.exe` could be found anywhere on the system and there would be no need of specifying the whole path - writing `pdflatex.exe` in the editor settings would be enough.

The procedure on how to set this environmental variable in Windows depends on the version you are using. In good old XP times this was found in the control panel under System in the "Advanced" tab.

But before you do all that, open a command line start->run->cmd and type in `pdflatex.exe` and check if it can be found.

[image]