# Compilation problem with miktex 2.9 on windows 8.1

Tags: errors, miktex, windows

I install MikTeX 2.9 on my Windows 8.1 but compilation always fails. 
Which version of MikTeX is compatible with Windows 8.1?

when i launch a document compilation, i always have the error message below

[image]

Comment: Welcome, you say the compilation fails, do you mean the document preparation or installation of MikTeX? If the first, you just have faulty code.

Comment: There is in general no issue with Win8.1 and MiKTeX 2.9: we will need to see some specific details to help.

Comment: miktex 2.9 works fine in windows 8.1 (and window 10).

Comment: Looks like the `pdflatex` executable is not found. You need to configure your LaTeX editor and tell it where MikTeX is installed, or add MikTeX to the PATH variable. However, I have no idea which editor it is (TeXMaker? TeXStudio?), so I can't really help you with that.

Comment: @coliasso: You should use the comment function to answer to commends. The answer button is just for answering your question.

Comment: ok, sorry. It is because I'm  new user on this forum

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up MiKTeX and TeXworks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60702/setting-up-miktex-and-texworks)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the pdflatex executable is not found. You need to configure your LaTeX editor and tell it where MikTeX is installed, or add MikTeX to the PATH variable.

Here's a [toturial on how to add MikTeX to your PATH variable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145465/configuration-of-texmaker-to-work-with-miktex-portable). It should also work for the non-portable version of MikTeX.

Comment: I have read and  the tutorial indicated  above,

Comment: I have read and  the tutorial indicated  above, at the step where I would had to paste a path at the PATH location, it wasn't possible (pasting there wasn't allowed); thus, my problem persists.

Comment: @coliasso: What do you mean by *"pasting there was not allowed"*? Can you not write anything there? Or is it just pasting that doesn't work?

Comment: I can't  paste, nor write there

Comment: @coliasso Then that seems to be a problem with your setup (assuming you clicked the right things). I can't really say what the problem might be. However, if you are the administrator of your PC, you could also use the *"Edit the system environment variables"* dialog and add MikTeX to the System-wide PATH variable, instead of the one for your own user account.